# Keyboard monitor behavior

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program that needs to monitor the keyboard for input without the return key being used.  When you use the first keystroke I get a weird result.  After that it works as expected.  Not sure how to resolve the first weird character.

My program:

```
import os, sys, termios, tty

def getch():  # getchar(), getc(stdin)  #PYCHOK flake
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
    return ch

def Jukebox():
    while True:
        print("Get key")
        key = getch()
        try:
            print("Number")
            Sel_char == int(key)
        except:
            try:
                print("Character")
                Sel_char == key.upper()
            except:
                print("Unknown")
                Sel_char = None
        print(key)
        
Jukebox()
```

When you run it and hit 'a', the result is:

```
Get key
Number
Character
Unknown
a
Get key
```

Hitting 'a' a second time provides the results I expect:

```
Number
Character
a
Get key
```

Why is the first 'a' not categorized as a character?  I don't understand how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the `Sel_char` at the beginning will solve the problem (I tested and seems fine)

```
def Jukebox():
    Sel_char=None
    while True:
        print("Get key")
        key = str(getch())
        print(key)

        try:
            print("Number")
            Sel_char == int(key)
        except:
           print("none")
        try:
            print("Character")
            Sel_char == key.upper()
        except:
            print("Unknown")
            Sel_char = None
        print(key)
```

In your case, if the first try-except block throws an exception, the variable `Sel_char` is not initialised. So, on the 2nd try-except block will fail again on the comparison.In the next turns will be ok because, the variable was set with `None`